# NPM package deep nested modules do no show in visual studio code suggestions

Tags: npm, module, package

I have published a package to the NPM registry, it has modules, and each module has modules and it keep nesting like this until I reach the specific functionality needed. please check the following image [Module Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u5GL.jpg)

When I was testing locally, I was able to call methods like this for example:
`util992.funcs.airtable.get.table(parameters)` since each module encapsulate other modules like the image above, and the final get module export a function called table like this `module.exports.table = (parameters) => { return 'table after processing'}`
`
Visual studio was showing me the modules suggestions along the way, please check the following image [Suggestions on the local environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkcoO.png)

Now I have published the package to the public NPM Registry, however, when I install it, and try to use it, visual studio doesn't show the nested modules anymore, it seems to stop suggesting after 2 or 3 levels of nesting. Please check the following image [No suggestions when module installed from NPM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DzcD.png)

However If I go an call the get.table function as I did above, ignoring that visual studio doesn't show me anything along the way, the function still works just as expected.
I feel it's just an issue that it's not showing after a specific nesting level, but functionality is not affected. Please check the following image [Function still work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky2RL.png)

Could you please help me understand what's going on, and how to fix that if possible?